# WooCommerce > Мини-корзина

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress-плагины, cart

У мини-корзины нужно поменять ссылки двух нижних кнопок, они перенаправляют не туда, куда нужно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашёл файл, отвечающий за мини-корзину.

```
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/mini-cart.php
```

Нашёл строки кода, отвечающие за вывод этих кнопок и их контента

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_before_buttons' ); ?>

<p class="woocommerce-mini-cart__buttons buttons"><?php do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons' ); ?></p>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_after_buttons' ); ?>
```

На сайте в коде это выглядит вот так

[image: Код кнопок в DevTools]

И нигде не могу найти, кто задаёт ссылки этим кнопкам. Как мне их поменять?
Сайт на WordPress + конструктор WP Bakery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В настройках Woocommerce есть привязка к странице корзины. Данные берутся оттуда.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вероятнее всего был установлен вукоммерс с демо страничкой, а затем ещё одну сделали, а поскольку два одинаковых слага /slug /постоянная ссылка быть не может, то второй страничке добавился номер два. Переименуйте слаг или выберите другую страничку.